# Visual Studio Code cannot debug program

Tags: c#

I am trying to use the C# extension in VS code to debug a program, however when I try to run without debugging I get the message "Cannot launch program setting the 'outFiles' attribute might help".

[image: Where my files are in the editor]

My launch.json file

```
 "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${file}"
        }
    ]
}
```

My C# code

```
using System; 


    // Class declaration 
    class Geeks { 

        // Main Method 
        static void Main(string[] args) { 


        } 
    }
```

Comment: You launch.json is wrong. This is for node. How did you add this launch.json?

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments you are using the `launch.json` for a Node project.

The Visual Studio Code C# extension can generate the assets you need to build and debug.

You can generate them through the Command Palette (View > Command Palette) by typing '.NET', and running .NET: Generate Assets for Build and Debug. This command will generate the necessary `launch.json` and `tasks.json` configuration files (under the `.vscode` folder).

See [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp) and [debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging)